# Emedding flash in HTML for IE 8

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, embed

this is the code I've used to embed my flash file:

```
<object id="flash" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="950" height="360" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" align="centre">
<param name="movie" value="/media/flash_final.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="950" height="360" src="../media/flash_final.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" name=" Web" bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="high"></embed>
</object>
```

It does display on IE 8 however it does not maintain the width and height dimensions I have set. I have also made sure that my flash is 960 x 360. How can I get it to show my desired size in a way which will still be compatible with other browsers? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by adding css style width and height. Manish suggested it in another thread. Here's the code that worked for me:

```
<p> </p>
<p>
<object id="flash" style="width: 950px; height: 350px;" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="950" height="360" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" align="centre">
<param name="movie" value="/media/flash_final.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="950" height="360" src="../media/flash_final.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" name="Web" bgcolor="#ffffff" quality="high"></embed>
</object>
<!--[if !IE]>-->                  
<object id="flash" style="width: 950px; height: 350px;" width="950" height="360" name="Web" data="media/flash_final.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="movie" value="media/flash_final.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /> <!--<![endif]--> <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" border="0" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /> </a> <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]--></p>
<p> </p>
```

Thanks again guys. God bless!

Answer (score 1):

Use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), it simplifies a lot the job of embedding the flash movie in HTML, it works cross browser like a charm and it allows you to set up an alternative content and target an specific version of the Flash Player really easily.

For example (I am posting only the relevant parts of the HTML):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.embedSWF("media/flash_final.swf", "flashmovie", "960", "360", "10.0.0", "media/expressInstall.swf");
        </script>

<!-- And in you body: -->  
<div id="flashmovie">
    Alternative content!    
</div>
```

Comment: hey danii, thanks. tried that but it did not show at all on IE or other browsers.

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial on the SWFObject page? Make sure to download the current version (2.2)

Comment: Hi i tried again this time i changed the div names. it shows but it still does not stretch out. IE 8 sucks! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I didn't solve your problem... yeah IE8 sucks big time ;)